# Переливающийся текст. Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Я хочу, чтобы текст объекта `Label()` постепенно менял цвет с синего на зелёный и потом обратно. Желательно чтобы смена цвета в одну сторону занимала примерно 5 секунд. Возможно ли это реализовать, и если да то как?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как вариант.

```
import tkinter as tk

def change_color(step=0):
    g = abs((step*8) % 512 - 255)
    b = 255 - g
    lbl.configure(fg=f"#00{g:0>2x}{b:0>2x}")
    root.after(5000 * 8 // 256, lambda: change_color(step+1))
    

root = tk.Tk()
lbl = tk.Label(root, text="Переливающийся текст", font="-size 20")
lbl.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)
root.after(1, change_color)
root.mainloop()
```